# VBA Access SQL Server table insert behaves differently

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have a problem when changing access code to SQL Server. I am trying to save the data in SQL Server, not in the Access database.

Access code

```
SELECT MAX("SPR-" & VAL(Replace([RequestID],"SPR-",""))+1) AS AutoID 
FROM Tb_Request;
```

SQL Server:

```
SELECT FORMAT(MAX(1 + REPLACE(RequestID, 'SPR-', '')),'SPR-#') AS RequestNo 
FROM dbo.PilotRequest
```

I think I changed correctly because I checked in SQL Server, the result is correct.

[image]

When I apply this code in Access, the result looks like this:

[image]

(There is data in the `dbo.PilotRequest` table, which is '5555'.)

Is there anyone who knows the reason for this?

Comment: you say that you have `5555` but your picture shows that you query `5556`

Comment: No, that's not. SPR-5556 is correct one because I made query like that. But in the Access program, I get '0PR-#' which needs to be like 'SPR-5556'. I do not know why this happens.

Comment: have a close look at the properties of the _Request No_ combo box. maybe the wrong data is being displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the concatenation outside of the `Max`, else your `Max` will compare strings and fail (because there's a string inside it).

```
SELECT "SPR-" & MAX(VAL(Replace([RequestID],"SPR-",""))+1) AS AutoID 
FROM Tb_Request;
```